# Get process (service) name or description from PID in linux terminal

Tags: linux, ubuntu, service, process, pid

I have multiple java applications that run on my ubuntu server, all have their *.service file and start at boot.
When I try to get the process names with `top` or with `ls -l /proc/191358/exe` the process name is always `/bin/java` or something extra long but I want the process description as in the .service file "My application"
Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have any `java` services running, so can't really experiment with sample data for you, but the following will give you all running services with their PID.

```
systemctl -t service --state=active --no-pager --no-legend | awk '{print $1}' | while read -r service; do echo -e "${service}\t $(systemctl show --property MainPID --value ${service})" ; done
```

Feel free to tack on a trailing `grep` to get only the ones you're interested in:

```
systemctl -t service --state=active --no-pager --no-legend | awk '{print $1}' | while read -r service; do echo -e "${service}\t $(systemctl show --property MainPID --value ${service})" ; done | grep -E 'filter1|filter2|...'
```

Edit (adding description):

```
systemctl -t service --state=active --no-pager --no-legend | awk '{print $1}' | while read -r service; do echo -e "$(systemctl show --property MainPID,Description  --value ${service}|tr '\n' '\t')\t${service}" ; done
```

Comment: This is EXACTLY what I needed, I have looked for it for a long time now. Thank you so much! Just as an extra, although i dont think i will need it, can i get the service description from this?

Comment: @AlessandroValentino I've achieved this, see the edit. There may be output formatting options for systemctl that make the `tr` unnecessary, but **it works for me™** ;)